# Getting Foursquare data

Tags: api, geolocation, location, foursquare

I'm working on an app which shows locations of restraunts,coffee shops etc. I wanted to ask if it is possible to use foursquare data and if Foursquare offers such a service.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Search Venues API
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

**example:**

Search Coffee Shop (categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735)
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735&ll=40.7,-74&oauth_token=(YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN)

Search Restaurant (categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735)
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1c4941735&ll=40.7,-74&oauth_token=
(YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN)

--

You can show category list with Venue Categories API
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories

Comment: Thanks very much Kosuke , so I can't add my POIs from foursquare? and if not do you know any other service which I can get it via an API? Thanks

Comment: @m0j1 You can add POI (called `Venue`) with venues/add API https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/add